# Minimal Kiosk GUI on PI

Tags: python, c++, xorg, opengles

I'm trying to work out how to build a minimal OpenGL application on Raspian.

Once complete, I don't require command line or Window Manager access (outwith the Application itself) however will require HIDs ideally including interfaces for touch.

Really don't have a clue where to start with this... I suppose what I'd like is basically to run directly in X out of the Command Line.

Any suggestions as to how one might achieve this?

Comment: X takes care of the HID stuff and yes you can run a single application in it without a window manager -- that's more or less how it normally works, just the "single application" is usually a desktop environment core or window manager.  Have a look at `man xinit`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider 2D Game engines/libraries ? Because OpenGL/OpenVG are low-level the added "belt and suspenders" of those libs will make your life much easier - **especially considering input handling , too** :

http://www.raylib.com/

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib

On the Raspberry Pi technologies incorporating hardware accelleration are preferable (look for OpenGL **ES** support !) - software rendering might give results which are unbearable.